# Secret dependencies in a Clojure Heroku project

Tags: heroku, clojure, leiningen

How can I add secret dependencies to a Clojure project on Heroku without putting them in a public repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create a folder in the root directory of the project

mkdir repo

2) Install dependencies to the repo using the maven command

mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar 
                                                                              -DgroupId=your.groupId 
                                                                              -DartifactId=your-artifactId 
                                                                              -Dversion=version 
                                                                              -Dpackaging=jar 
                                                                              -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo

3) Be careful to remove .pom and jar from .gitignore

4) git add repo

5) Edit project.clj and add the line

:local-repo "repo"

Leiningen will look for your secret dependencies in repo and in public repositories for all other dependencies.